# Perl - reading cyclic logfile backwards

Tags: perl, binary, freebsd, logfile

I'm currently using Perl to read a logfile backwards using the aptly named File::ReadBackwards module. However, the first line it returns only contains

```
CLOG� ��
```

Am I doing something wrong by trying to read the last line of a cyclic logfile?

This is the relevant code:

```
use File::ReadBackwards;
my $filePath = '/var/log/';
my @fileNames = ('gateways.log', 'system.log');

for(my $i = 0; $i <= @fileNames; $i++){
    scanFile($filePath,$fileNames[$i]);
    sleep(60);
}

sub scanFile(){
    my $handle = File::ReadBackwards->new($_[0] . $_[1]);
    my $line = $handle->readline;
    return $line
}
```

EDIT: I just read this - https://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Why_can't_I_view_view_log_files_with_cat/grep/etc%3F_(clog)

I can't seem to find a module or the likes that already reads these, can anyone point me the right way to extract lines from this CLog?

Comment: `$i <= @fileNames` should be `$i <= $#fileNames` or `$i < @fileNames`

Comment: Or simply use `foreach my $filename (@fileNames) { scanFile($filePath, $filename); }` and you don't have to care about an incrementor. Way more perlish. :)

Comment: What method has been used to generate your cyclic log file?

Comment: @Borodin The logfile was created by PFSense, I'm not entirely sure how it does that. I remember reading something about it being binary.

Comment: @AruneshSingh It still gives back the same output, both with $# and the foreach loop.

Comment: If that is binary-file, and you know the structure; then use [unpack](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html), to convert it in human readable format.

Comment: clog already does this, currently I'm trying to get my lines into my program using the perl shell command execution (``) - clog -f /var/log/system.log | grep 1 - which returns ALL of the log file sadly, trying to find out how to only return the last line at the moment. I'm kind of a UNIX noob.

Comment: do `tail -1` on place of `grep 1`.Or, If you can show the log-file structure , It will also work with same script  with some *minor changes*.

Comment: If you're not really interested in using perl, you could use the shell command "tac": clog -f /var/log/system.log | grep 1 | tac

Comment: If you're willing to use the `clog` command-line utility then you can get get the last line with `print((qx{clog /var/log/system.log})[-1])`. Although that's wasteful, it's the only way unless you want to implement your own CLOG file handler

Comment: The C source of the FreeBSD `clog` utility is [available here](http://software.wheelhouse.org/syslogd/). It's relatively simple code and wouldn't be too much trouble to rewrite the `read_log` function in Perl

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys, I got more than one point to work off of now. :)

Comment: I am using Perl not explicitly to just read logfiles but as an easy way to send messages based on these log files to a Slack channel.

Comment: @NicoWeiss: It sounds like it may be worth my time to write a CPAN module to deal with this. Would you be able to put a sample log file online that I can use for testing?